# For what values of $x$ is the line tangent to the graph of $f(x) = (2x + 1)^2 (3x - 4)^2$

Tags: calculus

For what values of $x$ is the line tangent to the graph of $f(x) = (2x + 1)^2 (3x - 4)^2$  parallel to the line $y = 7$?

(Sorry if it doesn't format right, but if anyone would be willing to explain to me how i can find the answer from just the equations themselves instead of using my calculator. Thanks!)

Comment: Have you worked on it? Can you show any idea?

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Have you found $f'(x)?$  Or, If you were stuck from the start, please let us know how far you've gone through calculus (or which semester, 1, 2, 3 of calculus are you currently in?)  The line $y=7$ is a horizontal line with slope $0$. And verify that $y' = 0.$  So if you can take the derivative of $f(x)$, and then set $f'(x) =0$, you can solve for $x$. The solution(s) you get for $x$ would be points where $f'(x)=0$  and is tangent to the line $y=7$

Comment: HINT: parallel lines means that the lines have the same inclination, i.e. the same value of $a$ in the general form of a line $f(x)=ax+b$. What is the inclination of $f(x)=7$?

Comment: I suggest you try to find where $\frac {df}{dx} = \frac {dy}{dx}$  Any idea why I would make such a suggestion?  I will also tell you that two of the values you are looking for are $\frac 43, -\frac 12,$ and a 3rd point lies between them.   Any idea why I say that?

Answer (score 1):

Since the line $y=7$ has slope zero, we wish to find all points $x$ for which $f^\prime(x)=0$.

Using the product rule, we have
\begin{align*}
f^\prime(x) 
&= 4 \, {\left(3 \, x - 4\right)}^{2} {\left(2 \, x + 1\right)} + 6 \, {\left(3 \, x - 4\right)} {\left(2 \, x + 1\right)}^{2} \\
&= 2\,(3\,x-4)(2\,x+1)\bigl(2\,(3\,x-4)+3\,(2\,x+1)\bigr) \\
&= 2\,(3\,x-4)(2\,x+1)(12 \, x - 5)
\end{align*}
Hence $f^\prime(x)=0$ for 
\begin{align*}
x &= \frac{5}{12} &
x &= \frac{4}{3} &
x &= -\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}